# Trying to capture x: y: positions using VNFaceObservation

Tags: ios, swift, face-recognition

I am using the below code to capture and draw the features of a face. However, trying to capture the x: y: positions are not consistent between images. I realize I am not capturing it correctly, So if anyone could provide some guidance. I want to use the x: y: to add a subview of another image. Much appreciated. 
John.

```
 var noseCrestPoint = CGPoint()
    var noseCrestPointX = CGFloat()
    var noseCrestPointY  = CGFloat()

    context?.saveGState()
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
    if let landmark = face.landmarks?.noseCrest {
        for i in 0...landmark.pointCount - 1 { // last point is 0,0
            let point = landmark.normalizedPoints[i]
            if i == 0 {
                context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: x + CGFloat(point.x) * w, y: y + CGFloat(point.y) * h))
                noseCrestPoint = CGPoint(x: x + CGFloat(point.x) * w, y: y + CGFloat(point.y) * h)
                noseCrestPointX =  noseCrestPoint.x
                noseCrestPointY =  noseCrestPoint.y
            } else {
                context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + CGFloat(point.x) * w, y: y + CGFloat(point.y) * h))
            }
        }
    }
    context?.setLineWidth(3.0)
    context?.drawPath(using: .stroke)
    context?.saveGState()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution. The first block of code is drawing the face, the second is placing my other image within the boundingBox near the eyes.

```
    // draw the face rect
    let w = face.boundingBox.size.width * image.size.width
    let h = face.boundingBox.size.height * image.size.height
    let x = face.boundingBox.origin.x * image.size.width
    let y = face.boundingBox.origin.y * image.size.height
    let faceRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
    context?.saveGState()
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context?.setLineWidth(3.0)
    context?.addRect(faceRect)
    context?.drawPath(using: .stroke)
    context?.restoreGState()



let eyeImageView = UIImageView()
    let eyeImage = UIImage (named:"eyes2.png")
   // eyeImageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w/2, height: h/4)
    eyeImageView.image = eyeImage;
    eyeImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: x + (w/4), y: y, width: w/1.5, height: h/3))
```

This resolved my issue. 
Hope someone finds this helpful.
Regards
JZ

Comment: Instead of adding a subview i used the .draw(in:CGRect feature to solve the issue.